# jQuery Click event not working with not function

Tags: jquery

I have page where as file is loading. That js file contains the followin    `$(links).unbind('click').not('.useful').click(this.clickfunction);`

I don't have control to change the above code.

But I want to add a click event on `.useful` but it is not working. Is this because of the above code?

I have tried the following codes but not working.

```
$('.useful').on('click', function(e) {
          console.log('a');
        });
        $('.useful').bind('click', function(e) {
          console.log('b');
        });
        $('.useful').click(function(e) {
          console.log('c')
        });
```

Comment: Is the code that you don't have control over loading before or after the code that you do have control over?

Comment: Most likely, `.useful` is a dynamic element, and isn't there when you bind the event handler. Try using `$(document).on('click', '.useful', ...` to see if that's the issue.

Comment: I have tried both. Execute my code above that code and also after that code

Comment: yes the .useful is a dynamic element. I tried the `$(document).on('click', '.useful')` but not working

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
<input type="button" class="usefull" id ="usefull" value="Click">
```

> jQuery

```
$("#usefull").click(function(){
    alert("you are clicked");
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rushil_pachchigar/topL4t1w/)

Comment: Okay you means your files loading after sometimes?